# How to convert data in Excel to XML

Tags: xml, excel, export-to-xml

My requirement is as follows

I want to convert below data in Excel to XML in this format.

Last Name   Sales     Country   Quarter

Smith   $16,753.00    UK    Qtr 3

Johnson $14,808.00    USA   Qtr 4

Williams    $10,644.00 UK   Qtr 2

```
<data-set>
<record1>
   <LastName>Smith</LastName>
   <Sales>16753</Sales>
</record1>
<record2>
   <Country>USA</Country>
   <Quarter>Qtr 4</Quarter>
 </record2>
 <record1>
   <LastName>johnson</LastName>
   <Sales>14808</Sales>
</record1>
<record2>
   <Country>USA</Country>
   <Quarter>Qtr 4</Quarter>
</record2>
</data-set>
```

I have tried with Developer-XML Source but it says its not exportable, I have data in the sequence only, i.e record1 tag has 2 columns then record2 has another 2 , Please help

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/xml.html

Answer (score 0):

Read this tutorial [HERE](http://xls2xml.appspot.com/tutorial)

Tutorial has really easy and basic example which will help you to achieve your goal. You have to read cell and set data based on sequence you mentioned in your question

```
try {
  XmlGenner x = XMLGennerSingleton.getXmlGenner();
  x.setCustomRows(1000);
  x.setSubRootElementName("Student");
  x.setProgressBar(jProgressBar1);
  x.generateXML_Item("c:/temp/in.xls", "c:/temp/out.xml");

} catch (Exception ex) {

}
```

Comment: Can you pls tell me if there is way to convert from EXCEL using source. An example is given in the link but the schema is very simple. I am asking a simple way because my excel has 400 columns and 4 lakh rows. Please help   http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/xml.html

Comment: Well you have to have map each column as its independent element in your xml no alternative best of my knowledge. Number of rows doesn't matter whether its 1 or 1 million.

Comment: your site shows exactly what I want, I want tags inside tags, which are mapped to Excel columns. But I am unable to understand the method, what tool to use , how to do. Can you pls elaborate it. Thanks

Comment: You will need two libraries including xls2xml, (jxl and xls2xml) by adding those libraries you can easily generate the output XML. You can download them from same link (Just hit download button) and add  those jar files in your project and you are good to go.